# I want to create a navbar with dropdown menu but my drop-down over lapping my main menu

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want to create a navbar with a drop-down menu but my drop-down menu is overlapping main menu. I want to put dropdown menu under main menu. How can i move drop-down with div tag slight down side to match with ending of main menu.
later i'll hide it and make it available only when hover on main menu option.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>GTU Students-Care</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width= device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Assistant|Barlow|Dosis|Gothic+A1|Monoton|Open+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
    header {
            background-color: #5495ff;
            color: white;
            padding: 35px;
    }
    #gtu-header-home {
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-size: 3.5em;
        font-family:'Barlow', sans-serif;
        text-shadow: -1px 0px blue, 0px 1px blue, 1px 0px blue, 0px -1px blue;
    }
    #gtu-header-detail {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    #footer-copyright {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
    }
    footer {
        background-color: #9baac4;
        padding: 25px;
    }
    ul.navbar {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: gray;
    }
    .navbar a{
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .navbar li{
        font-size: 26px;
        font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    #innerlist-1, #innerlist-2 {
        background-color: white;
        position: absolute;
        min-width: 3cm;
    }
    .innerlist a{
        color: gray;
        padding: 0px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 id="gtu-header-home">GTU Students Care</h1>
        <p id="gtu-header-detail">Tutorials | Question papers | Solution</p>
    </header>
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="#">Semester</a>
                <div id="innerlist-1" class="innerlist">
                    <a href="#">First</a>
                    <a href="#">Second</a>
                    <a href="#">Third</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Branch</a>
                <div id="innerlist-2" class="innerlist">
                    <a href="#">Computer</a>
                    <a href="#">Electronics</a>
                    <a href="#">Civil</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <footer>
        <div>
            <p id="footer-copyright">Copyright@ GTU Students Care</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code and dropdown show on hover. I think this will help you

```css
  header {
            background-color: #5495ff;
            color: white;
            padding: 35px;
    }
    #gtu-header-home {
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-size: 3.5em;
        font-family:'Barlow', sans-serif;
        text-shadow: -1px 0px blue, 0px 1px blue, 1px 0px blue, 0px -1px blue;
    }
    #gtu-header-detail {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    #footer-copyright {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
    }
    footer {
        background-color: #9baac4;
        padding: 25px;
    }
    ul.navbar {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: gray;
    }
    .navbar a{
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        color: white;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .navbar li{
        font-size: 26px;
        font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #innerlist-1, #innerlist-2 {
        background-color: white;
        position: absolute;
        min-width: 3cm;
    }
    .innerlist{
     display:none;
    }
    .navbar > li:hover .innerlist{
     display:block;
    }
    .innerlist a{
        color: gray;
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

```html
 <header>
        <h1 id="gtu-header-home">GTU Students Care</h1>
        <p id="gtu-header-detail">Tutorials | Question papers | Solution</p>
    </header>
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="#">Semester</a>
                <div id="innerlist-1" class="innerlist">
                    <a href="#">First</a>
                    <a href="#">Second</a>
                    <a href="#">Third</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Branch</a>
                <div id="innerlist-2" class="innerlist">
                    <a href="#">Computer</a>
                    <a href="#">Electronics</a>
                    <a href="#">Civil</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <footer>
        <div>
            <p id="footer-copyright">Copyright@ GTU Students Care</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
```